# Laravel return true validation for incorrect urls

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

in laravel i want to check simple url such as :

```
http://www.google.com
http://google.com
www.google.com
http://www.google.com
http://www.google
```

unfortunately laravel validation code as

```
['redirect_url' => 'required|url']
```

return `false` for this urls:

```
www.google.com
```

and return true for `http://www.google` address, how to check correctly urls in laravel, this validation is not best validation for urls

Answer (score 4):

You can use [regex](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-regex) validation rule for URL validation

```
 ['redirect_url' => ['required','regex:/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i']]
```

Comment: i get this error: `preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found`

Comment: @mahdipishguy Sorry..
Patter has a '|' symbol so, it is consider as a new validation rule.

Comment: thanks, this validation return true for this url `www.google`

Answer (score 1):

Before validation check if string contains `http://` or `https://` with this code:

```
if(!(starts_with($url, "http://") || starts_with($url, "https://")) {
        $url = "http://".$url;
}
```

Function `starts_with()` is helper function from Laravel. [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#strings)

Answer (score 0):

The regex solution that [Jay Dhameliya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34285711/50866) provided is probably the best one for your scenario but I just thought I would explain why the url validator doesn't work as you expected.

If you look at the illuminate/validation/Validator validateURL [function](https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/master/Validator.php#L1248-L1271) it is expecting a the following to be specified as part of the URL.

- protocol ( http/https/etc )
- optional basic auth
- a domain or ip address
- optional port
- a trailing / or nothing or / followed by something else

There doesn't seem to be any alternatives provided for this validator method or ways to say don't require the protocol. So once again a custom regex seems the best option. If you are planning on using it in more than one place you might want to consider creating your own Custom Validation Rule see the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules) for details.

Comment: yes, i know but this the regex return true for this url `www.google`, this url isnt correct but return true;

Comment: You could use the validateActiveUrl method https://github.com/illuminate/validation/blob/master/Validator.php#L1280-L1285 to validate the domain actually resolves. There are regex's that are more precise that might work for what your wanting to see, however google is a valid tld see https://www.registry.google/ and you could register the domain www so technically its right.